# How to return HTML without JQuery-generated code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using JQuery's `html()` method to get the HTML of a div on my page. However it is returning a string containing all the JQuery-generated code too:

```
<ul><li id="fact_1" class="jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Factory 1: (1-1000)</a><ul id="fact_1_children"><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>348</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>813</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>447</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>112</li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>277</li></ul></li><li id="fact_2" class="jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Factory 2: (1001-2000)</a><ul id="fact_2_children"><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1833</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1142</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1038</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1245</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1891</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1532</li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>1741</li></ul></li><li id="fact_3" class="jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Factory 3: (2001-3000)</a><ul id="fact_3_children"><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2895</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2974</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2120</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2230</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2854</li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>2413</li></ul></li><li id="fact_4" class="jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Factory 4: (3001-4000)</a><ul id="fact_4_children"><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>3495</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>3951</li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>3931</li></ul></li><li id="fact_5" class="jstree-open jstree-last"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Factory 5: (4001-5000)</a><ul id="fact_5_children"><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>4969</li><li class="jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>4645</li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>4517</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I need to be getting a string containing only the raw HTML, like this:

```
<ul id="tree"><li id="fact_1" class="jstree-open"><a>Factory 1: (1-1000)</a><ul id="fact_1_children"><li>348</li><li>813</li><li>447</li><li>112</li><li>277</li></ul></li><li id="fact_2" class="jstree-open"><a>Factory 2: (1001-2000)</a><ul id="fact_2_children"><li>1833</li><li>1142</li><li>1038</li><li>1245</li><li>1891</li><li>1532</li><li>1741</li></ul></li><li id="fact_3" class="jstree-open"><a>Factory 3: (2001-3000)</a><ul id="fact_3_children"><li>2895</li><li>2974</li><li>2120</li><li>2230</li><li>2854</li><li>2413</li></ul></li><li id="fact_4" class="jstree-open"><a>Factory 4: (3001-4000)</a><ul id="fact_4_children"><li>3495</li><li>3951</li><li>3931</li></ul></li><li id="fact_5" class="jstree-open"><a>Factory 5: (4001-5000)</a><ul id="fact_5_children"><li>4969</li><li>4645</li><li>4517</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Is there any way to do this? This in advance.

Comment: No, once the DOM is modified, it is modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the HTML, before its modified, to a `var`, you will have it for later.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought of this and am working on it now.